# Show that the $L^1$ and $L^2$ norms are not equivalent on the set of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $E$ be the vector space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$.
Show that the $L^1$-norm is not equivalent to the $L^2$-norm.

My thought was that, given a sequence of functions $f_n\in E$ which converges to the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, we can see that $$||f_n||_1=\int_0^1|f_n|dx \to \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx=2\sqrt{0}+2\sqrt{1}=2 $$ However,
$$||f_n||_2=\left(\int_{0}^1 (f_n)^2 dx \right)^{1/2}\to \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}dx\right)^{1/2}$$ Since this sequence converges with respect to one norm but not the other we can conclude that they are not equivalent.

Does this argument make any sense? It feels like it doesn't make sense to talk about the norm of a function that isn't in the space $E$ since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\notin E$. But the hint for the problem says to consider truncating said function near 0.

Comment: You have shown that the sequence $(f_n) \subseteq E$ is bounded in one norm and unbounded in the other one, so the norms cannot be equivalent. Sounds fine for me.

Comment: You don't need those $f_n$ whatsoever. Your counterexample is exactly  the continuous function on $(0,1)$, $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: @alphaomega The counterexample is not in $E$ though, it wouldn't make sense to take the norm of it. We cannot even define an integral norm on the set of all continuous functions on (0,1) since they are not all integrable or square-integrable.

Comment: Your argument is a good idea but missing detail. Find a sequence of functions $f_n$ that are in both $L^1$ and $L^2$ and are of bounded norm in $L^1$ but unbounded norm in $L^2$. Take $f_n(x) = {1 \over \sqrt{x}} 1_{[{1 \over n},1]}(x)$ for example.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter oh right. it's $[0,1]$, not $(0,1)$. My bad.

Comment: @copper.hat What does $1_{[\frac1n,1]}(x)$ mean?

Comment: Indicator function of set $[{1 \over n},1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just consider the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n \ge 1} \subset C[0,1]$ defined by $f_n(x)=n x^n$

Then $||f_n||_1 = \int_{0}^1 nx^ndx=\frac{n}{n+1}$ . Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} ||f_n||_1=1$

But $||f_n||_2=\int_{0}^1 |nx^n|^2dx=\frac{n^2}{2n+1} \to \infty \text{ as } n \to \infty$